# Array.remove() wont work more than once in onClickListener()

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have a listview in one of my Activities that has a delete button inside of each row. When I click the delete button I want to remove that row value from two different arrays. The first array is the list array that shows the information in the listview and the second is for my sharedPreference array which is the data populating the listview. This works fine the first time I run it but if I try deleting more than one row without recreating the view it won't work.

Here is my code:

```
deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //this will delete the row from the list view
            list.remove(position);

            //this deletes the value from the sharedPreference 
            favoritesList.remove(position);

            notifyDataSetChange();
        } 
}
```

This works the fine the first time I click the delete button in a row but if I want to delete another row, I click the delete button on a different row and while the row is removed from the listview it isnt removed from my favoritesList array. Which means the *favoritesList.remove(postion)* is only working the first time. It's almost like favoritesList isn't being refreshed and its just trying to remove the same value no matter what row I click on. Which is weird because *list.remove(position)* works fine.

So how do I get *favoritesList(position)* to run more than once without breaking? I can post more code if need be but I figured this would be enough. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the whole custom adapter for my listview:

```
public class ItemCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> favoritesList;
private Context context;
//private final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
String[] favorites;

public ItemCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context, String[] favorites) {
    this.list = list;

    this.context = context;
    this.favorites = favorites;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;
    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //System.out.println(favoritesList);

    favoritesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(favorites));

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, null);
    }

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
    listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list.remove(position);
            favoritesList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Somebody wants to close this question, it´s marked as off topic (seems not to be a programming question). Why? It looks like a programming question...

Comment: maybe you set the wrong value for position. Can you show how you are getting the `position` value and can you show your favoritesList initialization?

Comment: and if you talking about `sharedPreferences`, what is the relation for `favoritesList` to `sharedPreferences` ?

Comment: Added where I get position above.

Comment: I think the problem is that you always create a new ArrayList at the beginning of `getView` method. I think you must remove from `favorites` not from `favoritesList`

Comment: Now I see that `favorites` is a String array, so you have to create the `favoritesList` outside the `getView` method as an instance variable, then it should work with deleting.

Comment: Do you get what I mean? You are creating the `favoritesList` every time `getView` is called as a new ArrayList from `favorites` so it´s always with that values.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Opiatefuchs said above, all I had to do was move *favoritesList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(favorites));* outside of *getView()*.